# When is it bad to make a method of a class return itself?

Tags: c++, class

When is it bad to make the return type of a method its own class? for example:

```cpp
class Stuff{
public:
    Stuff &change_name(std::string name) {...} // is this better,
    void   change_name(std::sring name) {...}  // than this?
};
```

Is it better to make `change_x` return `Stuff` or just make it `void`? because I don't really see a reason why someone will make a sequence of command when calling the method `change_name`, or is it may be a good practice to always return a supposed to be `void` method to return its class?

Comment: If its useful to chain your methods then return `this` otherwise don't

Comment: If there are multiple things that the user might want to change then returning a reference allows the user to chain multiple setters, e.g. `x.change_name("john").change_age(33).change_address("...");` This pattern has a name (can't remember what it is however).

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is useful if you have a class that is meant to change its state repeatedly. Or more succinct, a class that has its main purpose in changing its state by its client code. As in general, you should try to minimize the number of possible states a class instance can be in, use the `return *this` technique only when its API is clearly superior compared to `void` member function return types.

The prototypical example here is a builder-class. When you have a complicated constructor of some class to call, with many parameter that depend on several inputs, it can make sense to wrap the construction into a separate builder class. Example client code:

```
Builder b{/* ... few arguments */ };

b.setName(/* ... */).
  setId(/* ...*).
  setSomeNumber(/* ...*).
  setSomeState(/* ...*).
  setOtherState(/* ...*);

Object thatsWhatIAmInterestedIn = b.construct();
```

This method chaining is terse compared to the distinct invocation of `void` member functions, and it will easily be recognized as a builder process.